# get window.location.hostname in analytics gtag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, onclick

I'm trying to get the current hostname inside an iframe `onclick` but this is not working.

Don't know if I'm doing wrong or if it's possible this way...

My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<body>
<a href="#" onClick="gtag('event', 'myevent', {'event_category': 'mycategory', 'event_label': '+window.location.hostname '});">see</a>

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-XX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX',{ 'anonymize_ip': true });
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why you would even need this information in the label, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error in the console ?
Otherwise the issue is maybe just escaping issue:
you have:

```
'event_label': '+window.location.hostname '}
```

while it should probably be:

```
'event_label': window.location.hostname}
```

Comment: But do you have any error in the console ? or just it's empty ?